# Changing python to read code differently?

Tags: python

When I make text adventures in python for my friends, I am constantly frustrated that I have to code the adventure upward since python reads code from top to bottom. For example:

```
def stage2():

def stage1():

def start():
```

Then so on and so forth.. Is there any way that I can make python read the code in a different way so that I can code text adventures from the top up?

Comment: an easy way would be to make a class and add the functions on the class. then you will be able to use any order you want

Comment: The functions aren't called until something calls them? What's the problem?

Comment: @Aesthete i think his problem is that he has to call stage2 from inside stage1 so he has to define 2 before 1

Comment: I get an error saying the stage functions aren't defined when I would run it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write your functions in whatever order you like, so long as they are *defined* before they are *called*.

For instance,

```
def start():
    print("Welcome to the adventure")
    stage1()

def stage1():
    print("You made it this far!")
    stage2()

# if you called start() here,
# you would have an error when stage1() tries to call stage2(),
# because the interpreter doesn't know what a stage2 is yet.

def stage2():
    print("Oops - you died.")

start()
```

works fine.

On the other side of things:

```
def test():
    if True:
        print("Yup")
    else:
        slartibartfast()

test()
```

runs fine because the interpreter never gets around to asking what a slartibartfast is ;-)

Comment: @TheNotGoodAtCodeGuy - basically, you just need to get the distinction between *defining* a function and *calling* it clear in your head, and you'll be able to avoid these kinds of issues.

Comment: Huh, strange... Because when I do this on my raspberry pi, it gives me an error telling me that the stage1 and stage2 functions aren't defined...